# What is this plant in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm new to Clash of Clans, i just came across this strange plant which when touched says "flower" and its title days 'Scary Pumpkin'.
[image: scary pumpkin]

Should I remove it using 25,000 elixir? What would it get me ?

Comment: I always thought it says "Mama" lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scary pumpkin will give you 75,000 elixir when it is removed. Make sure that your storages are not full!

Comment: By storages, you mean both the Gold and elixir ones?

Comment: @ABcDexter By storages, I am referring to elixir storages, as they are the ones that will be filled.

Comment: Ok, one final question : are you absolutely sure that they need to "be full" and not empty?

Comment: Sorry, that was totally my fault - i wrote full instead of empty. It has been fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, it worked... giving 75,000 elixir and 5 points for experience level :D

Answer (score 2):

My rec...  keep it around until you need it for one of those big 6,000,000 upgrades.  The decorations don't loose value and invaders can't take the 20% storage penalty like when they invade your containers.  Use it to put you right in range of your elixer goals.

Comment: I still have Christmas Trees.  25k gold to remove and rewards 75k.  The Halloween cauldron was last years 25K elixir decoration.  Wish I kept it around.

Answer (score 0):

Note that some people like to keep one around as a keepsake - kinda like saying *"Hey I was there for that event!"*.

If you're not one of those players then you'd be best to remove it for the 75000 elixir like @EpicGeeth said.

Comment: This should really be a comment rather than an answer itself